# How to check if multiple keys exists in nested (all) dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

To check if `'b' & 'c'` exists in `'a' & 'b'`.

```
test = {
    'a': {
        'b': [1234],
        'c': 'some_value'
    },
    'd': {
        'b': [5678],
        'c': ''
    }
}
```

**Approach1:** works as below but not great implementation if nested dictionary are huge in number. And also, You can't exactly notify which element doesn't exist. Let's say, `'c' not in 'a' , 'b' not in 'd' & 'c' not in 'd'` . In this case, it fails at second statement (but it doesn't notify that 3rd & 4th statements also fail). I need to get, which all doesn't exist.

```
try:
   v1 = test['a']['b']
   v2 = test['a']['c']
   v3 = test['d']['b']
   v4 = test['d']['c']
except Exception as err:
   print(err)
```

**Approach2:**

```
for k,v in test.items():
   if 'b' not in v:
       print("'b' doesn't exist in {}".format(test[k][v]))
   if 'c' not in v:
       print("'c' doesn't exist in {}".format(test[k][v]))
```

`Approach1` and `Approach2` seem to be not great. Any other better ways to handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two levels of nest, could you please try to count occurence of keys in lower-level dicts?
For example:

```
counter  = {}
for el in test.keys():
    for subkey in test.get(el).keys():
        if subkey not in counter.keys():
            counter[subkey] = 1.0
        else:
            counter[subkey] += 1.0
```

it'll return

```
{'b': 2.0, 'c': 2.0}
```

based on that you can identify duplicated values in your nested keys.

You could then use `set` to saw on which keys duplicates exist:

dupe keys

```
counter = {k : v for k, v in counter.items() if v > 1}    

#get only values with dupe records

{k:v for k, v in test.items()  if len(set(counter.keys()).intersection(v)) > 0}


> {'a': {'b': [1234], 'c': 'some_value'}, 'd': {'b': [5678], 'c': ''}}
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it, by getting the count. But again, will have to parse counter to know which exists and doesn't. Anything better feasible with efficiency and optimisation than 2 approaches ?

Comment: I just add part with ```set``` which can efficiently provide an information if duplicated keys are contained in first level of dict.